# Mootools list filter with periodical request to the server

Tags: javascript, list, filter, mootools, element

I have a html markup (online users list):

```
<div id="users">
   <div class="users_row" title="User1">User1</div>
   <div class="users_row" title="User2">User2</div>
   <div class="users_row" title="User3">User3</div>
   <div class="users_row" title="User4">User4</div>
</div>
```

My mootools js function below (periodical function every 5 seconds):

```
      get_users: function() {                   

                new Request.JSON({
                    initialDelay: 1,
                    delay: 10000,
                    limit: 25000,
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'handler.php', 

                        onSuccess: function(data){
                            if (data.users.length) {
                                data.users.each(function(u){
/*Wrong...*/                                    
new Element('div', {'html':u.name, 'class': 'user_row', 'title': u.name}).inject(document.id('users')); 

                                });     
                            }       
                        }
                });
        }
```

For example I get User1, User2, User3, User5 from my handler.php.
How can I rebuild my online users list?

```
 <div id="users">
       <div class="users_row" title="User1">User1</div>
       <div class="users_row" title="User2">User2</div>
       <div class="users_row" title="User3">User3</div>
       <!--<div class="users_row" title="User4">User4</div>!--> // Remove User4
       <div class="users_row" title="User5">User5</div> // Add User5
 </div>
```

P.S: This answer is not acceptable :)

```
document.id('users').set('html', '<div class="users_row" title="'+u.name+'">'+u.name+'</div>);
```

Thanks.

P.S: My JSON sample from the server:

```
{"users":[{"name":"User1"},{"name":"User2"},{"name":"User3"},{"name":"User5"}],"total":4}
```

Comment: does the total user number change after request? or you just replace the title & html of the markup you already have?

Comment: Yes. It may change. For example new members in the room. Or somebody left the room. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a sample of you JSON/request data?

Comment: Yes. Please check above. Thanks.

Comment: @user889349, posted an answer for you, let me know if it was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Check demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZrBw/)**

```
for (i = 0; i < users.users.length; i++) {
        var el = new Element('div', {
            'class': 'users_row',
            'html': users.users[i].name
        });
        el.inject(usersDivId);
    }
```